# how can i implement specific method from two different abstract class?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, java-8

I want to access all the methods(non-abstract+abstract) from `Class A`.

So i extended `Class A`, but here in `Class B` i want to access all non-abstract methods and only 10 abstract method - as I dont want to implement rest of the abstract methods of `class B`.

**Problem**:

1.I can't extend `Class B` because i have already extended `Class A`.

2.I can't put those 10 methods inside an interface because i also want to access the non-abstract methods from `class B`.

**what should be the correct approach to reuse those methods?.**

class A

```
abstract class A{
public void m1(){
    //do stuff
}
public void m2(){
    //do stuff 
}
// +30 more non abstract methods

public abstract void n1();
public abstract void n2();
// +30 more abstract method 
}
```

class  B

```
abstract class B{
public void a1(){
    //do stuff
}
public void a2(){
    //do stuff 
}
// +30 more non abstract methods

public abstract void b1();
public abstract void b2();
// +30 more abstract method 
 }
```

class C

```
class C extends A{
public  void n1(){
    //do stuff
}
public  void n2(){
    //do stuff
}
//+30 more abstract methods implemented

//But here i want all the non abstract methods and only 10 abstract methods of B
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to inherit only 10 methods from B? There's something wrong in here. What do you want achieve with that?

Comment: Although you might probably not like my answer; still a +1 for your question; as it gives interesting food for thought.

Comment: Do you have control over classes `A` and `B`? i.e. Can you modify them?

Comment: thanks for the surprising accept ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The serious non-answer here: stop; and step back now. Forget about doing this.

Chances are extremely high that your design is already in a very bad shape. As you should always prefer a complex network of simple classes over a simple network of complex classes.

*Inheritance* is **much** more than just writing down `A extends B`. It starts with: in that case, any A *is-a* B. Alone the number of methods you mention in your question indicate that your classes do not follow that simple rule; and probably they are violating others, too.

Thus: do not waste your time to understand how to add another 10 to to the  other **30** methods in your class. Spend your time to throw away everything; and build a **real** OO model.

You would start by understanding the problem domain; to derive meaningful,  helpful classes from that. Classes that focus on the problem to solve. Classes that follow the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) rules. Or remember the good old [FCoI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) paradigm.

Long story short: I would consider a class with more than 10 methods to be subject for refactoring; but *30 abstract* methods; that sounds (sorry) (almost) *outright crazy*.

Edit, on some of the comments: of course, it is possible that the OP has in fact a reasonable design; as there are examples of classes that come with a lot of methods (think of a typical Swing UI component for example). But (imho) the likelihood of a "bad" design is simple pretty high when dealing with a large number of *abstract* methods.

Comment: While I totally agree with the concepts presented in your answer (I've actually upvoted it), I don't like absolute rules in software, such as *I would consider a class with more than 10 methods to be subject for refactoring; but 30 abstract methods; that is (sorry) (almost) outright crazy*. I understand your point here, but would you consider `ArrayList` needs refactoring? It has 31 methods...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Everything written for Java 1.2 could use some refactoring.

Comment: And we are talking about 30 + 10 **abstract** methods here. Beyond that, how many of methods in ArrayList is one typically using? And on top of that: how often does one cast List to ArrayList to enable you to call methods that don't come with the List interface?!

Comment: As I said, I understand your point, and it´s a valid one. `ArrayList` is just an example of a class that has 31 methods and doesn't need refactoring, despite you only use a few methods from the `List` interface. My point is that there are different situations and different contexts, so making general claims such as *refactor when your class reaches 11 methods* might be the case for many situations, but not for *every* situation. Just my 2 cents, I don't want to start any controversy here :) On the other side, 30 methods + 10 abstract methods sounds like a nightmare design.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: `ArrayList` inherits from `AbstractList`, which only mandates to implement *two* `abstract` methods, plus overriding three additional methods for supporting mutability. All other methods of `ArrayList` are not required, but overridden for performance, so the authors could have stopped whenever the development expense seemed too high. You could remove them without breaking anything. This is entirely different to the OP’s situation where implementing the thirty methods is considered too expensive right from the start (but needed, for whatever reason).

Comment: @Holger OK, I used a BAD example. I understand all the points.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: I’m ok with saying that there are indeed reasonably designed classes with 30+ own methods, but the OP talks about *120* methods in `C`, 30+30 from `A` and 30+30 from `B`, though the OP wants to get away with only implementing 10 of the 30 `abstract` methods of `B`, however that is supposed to work. So maybe we can agree that a class with over hundred methods is very likely to have design issues…

Comment: And what a shame that the OP isn't giving away a single "beep" on what he thinks about our thoughts.

Comment: @Holger I absolutely agree, my point was not against what we are discussing here, but only against absolute claims. And I tried to give an example (a badly chosen one). Yes, what the OP has is a complete nightmare, I hope he can change and partition those classes... It not only violates every design principle and pattern over there, but also common sense. Who will maintain that code tomorrow, even if the OP makes it work today by means of some magic hack (such as the one he's asking about)? Again, I'm with all of you, guys, having 30 methods + 10 abstract methods to deal with really sucks...